# Resize all viewcontroller frames in tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController holding 4 controllers (navigation controllers). Now i would like change the frames of all 4 controller views, so
what is the best practice for this ?

**Note**: 
UITabBarController will always reset the frames of its container views, since it will try to fit them to its container view bounds.

Comment: so why are you trying to resize them?

Comment: well normally you don't do that but since you wanna do it, is all the controllers of tabBarController have same size?

Comment: @JigneshAgola Yes they do have the same size. I can manage to resize them while looping in the tabbarcontroller.viewcontrollers, but the i can not manage to stop the tabbarcontroller to force resize them back to its container bounds..

Comment: @Wain it is an experimental purpose.

Comment: how would you use it in the real world ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by creating custom tabbar controller.

Please check below screenshot for how to create custom tabbar to fulfil your requirement.

[image]

Once you create tabbar this way and change frame size of container it will look like as i have shown in next screen shot. You can change container frame size through coding as per your convenient.

[image]

Comment: This would have worked, but i needed to preserve UITabBarController class.
Check out my solution, i posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem and maintained the native UITabBarController :

Since the UITabBarController will force the view controllers' size to its bounds, I dynamically changed the **UITabBar** origin.y ( `tabBar.origin.y -= reduced size` ) and size.height  `tabBar.size.height += reduced size` ) so that the container frame for the viewcontrollers is forced to get smaller.

And than, to preserve the casual tab bar design, for each UITabBarItem in the tabBar, i pushed the **imageInset**.

This way there is no need to force change frames of multiple viewControllers views in tabBarController through observers for layer change or any other similar methods.

Comment: What do you mean you pushed the **imageInset**? What's the imageInset?

Comment: tabBarItem.imageInsets property.